# Conflict between gb4e and xyling

Tags: errors, linguistics, gb4e

I am trying to use both the gb4e and xyling packages (I've long used the former, the latter is new for me), and they produce an error when used in the same document (whichever order they're called in). Using either package on its own compiles fine. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{xyling}

\begin{document}

Dragons

\end{document}
```

This produces the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.101 \catcode`\^^M
                   =\active
?
```

Is there any good way to fix this?

Or, alternatively, I only need xyling for a very specific purpose, to make a metrical grid, as described in section 9 (p. 25) of the documentation:http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xyling/xyli-doc.pdf If there is a different package that can achieve the same effect without conflicting with other packages, that would also be a practical solution for me.

Comment: Simply reversing the order of the packages on it own does not solve the issue for me (as I noted), but Marijn's solution did the trick!

Comment: Sorry I hadn't noticed that. I'll delete my comment. The `xy` package uses `_` extensively which is why it's so sensitive to the use of `_` as an active character.

Comment: Although I would still suggest extracting just the code you need from `xyling` rather than loading the whole package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marijn's answer is, of course, a direct answer to the question. I'm adding this answer which is an indirect answer, since I think in this case it's the preferred route for the specific need mentioned in the question.

If you're only using the `xyling` package for its metrical grid code, I would recommend just copying the code into your document. Using `xyling` requires compilation with `latex+dvips`, which is likely not what you want. Although you can probably safely ignore all the warnings it produces if you use another compilation method (since you're not actually using any of its postscript code) it would be simpler just to use the code you need and avoid all the spurious warnings.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
% Metrical grid code from xyling
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{PXcnt}
\newcommand{\PX}[2][1]{%
\shortstack[c]{%
\whiledo{\value{PXcnt}<#1}
{\stepcounter{PXcnt}$\times$\\}#2\strut%
}\setcounter{PXcnt}{0}}

\newcommand{\PXl}[2][1]{%
\shortstack[l]{%
\whiledo{\value{PXcnt}<#1}
{\stepcounter{PXcnt}$\times$\\}#2\strut%
}\setcounter{PXcnt}{0}}

\newcommand{\PXr}[2][1]{%
\shortstack[r]{%
\whiledo{\value{PXcnt}<#1}
{\stepcounter{PXcnt}$\times$\\}#2\strut%
}\setcounter{PXcnt}{0}}
% Syntax: \PX[number of grid marks]{expression}
% An example:
%          \PX[2]{Fa}rah \PX{Faw}cett \PX[3]{Ma}jors

\usepackage{gb4e}


\begin{document}

Dragons

\PX[2]{Fa}rah \PX{Faw}cett \PX[3]{Ma}jors

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 4):

The `gb4e` package makes the `^` and `_` characters active, in order to allow subscripts and superscripts outside of math mode (i.e., in linguistic examples). This causes many problems with other packages when they try to use these characters with their normal meaning, for example `xyling` that tries to set the category code of `^^M`. This is acknowledged by `gb4e`, and there is an option to switch this behavior off, called `\noautomath`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\usepackage{xyling}

\begin{document}

Dragons

\end{document}
```

If you do need subscripts and superscripts later, you can switch the behavior back on with `\automath`.